# Can you show me an example of a lattice that would have one universal element and one null, but not all its elements complementable?

Tags: lattice-orders

I have a definition in a book:

a lattice $T$ can be complemented, if :

1. it has one universal element $U$ and one null $n$,
2. for each $x$ of $T$ can be associated at least one $\bar{x}$ of $T$, where
   $\left\{
   \begin{array}{ll}
      x \lor \overline{x} = U \\
      x \land \overline{x} = n \\
   \end{array}
   \right.$

Being a computer engineer, I understand this well.
What I can't figure, and for which I would like to have an example from you, is :

What could be a lattice $T$ that :

1. would have one universal element $U$ and one null $n$,
2. **but** (for each $x$ of $T$ can be associated at least one $\bar{x}$ of $T$, where $\left\{
   \begin{array}{ll}
      x \lor \overline{x} = U \\
      x \land \overline{x} = n \\
   \end{array}
   \right.$) **would not be verified** ?

Do you know an example, so that I can figure this myself clearer?

Comment: A totally ordered set with three elements. The middle element is not compkemented.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin has given an example. Quite often with such things there are small examples, and it is worth trying minimal or near-minimal configurations. This will also help you to understand the definitions and properties involved. Quite often if there is no small example, there is no finite example - and either you need infinitely many elements, or the thing is impossible. [This is not universal, but it is surprising - at least to me - how often it turns out to be useful]